# Does apigeex offer hosting with different cloud provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

Does apigee x offer hosting with different cloud providers? Can one try a Customer-managed runtime plane such as AWS machines?

What are necessary considerations to keep while migrating apigee edge to apigee X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/get-started/compare-apigee-products) states Apigee X is hosted on Google Cloud. Your only options for custom hosting providers are Apigee Edge and Apigee hybrid.

Answer (score 3):

You specifically mention the runtime plane: Apigee Hybrid is what you're looking for. In essence it allows you to put the Apigee API-proxy runtime engine in your own environment (e.g., AWS, or even on-prem).

Generally, Apigee Hybrid uses the same cloud management plane as Apigee-X, so as I see it, Apigee Hybrid is the "hybrid flavor of Apigee-X" which is otherwise a SaaS offering.

Comment: exactly, since the question covers Runtime Plane, Hybrid allows to install it on-prem or private cloud/cloud provider (AWS, Azure, GCP & so on.)